# Guava version 16.0 being used during runtime even though 18.0 is used during compile time

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, pom.xml, netflix

I am trying to run a project in wildfly. Following is the guava dependency version. I tried including 18.0 in the dependency management but it still uses 16.0. Been struggling with this for entire day, googled a lot but no solution on this.

[image]

Here is the stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.verizon.fieldops.equipmentservice.dao.cassandra.CassandraDAO.init(CassandraDAO.java:155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected Guava issue #1635 which indicates that a version of Guava less than 16.01 is in use.  This introduces codec resolution issues and potentially other incompatibility issues in the driver.  Please upgrade to Guava 16.01 or later.
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.checkGuava(SanityChecks.java:62)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.check(SanityChecks.java:36)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:68)
    ... 47 more
```

As request in the comment editing the description to add pom file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.verizon.fieldops</groupId>
    <artifactId>equipmentservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.00.004</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>equipmentservice</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <libs.path>${basedir}/libs</libs.path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Boot Web dependency -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot test framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java JMS API dependency -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring JMS dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <!-- OmegaCore Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.verizon.fieldops</groupId>
            <artifactId>OmegaCore</artifactId>
            <version>1.00.006</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${libs.path}/OmegaCore-1.00.006.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSR Annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandraDependency</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${libs.path}/cassandraDependency-1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${libs.path}/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hystrix (Circuit Breaker) dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.M9</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <!-- <finalName>MSTemplate</finalName> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>3.2.2</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope> -->
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>libs/</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.jar</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Repositories -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <description>Equipment service</description>
</project>
```

Comment: are you using maven / gradle?

Comment: I am using maven

Comment: Can you paste your pom file?

Comment: added pom file in the description

Comment: I don't see guava in your pom

Comment: It’s getting used by the Netflix hysterix. Check the screen which shows the dependency

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing the dependency called [archaius-core 0.7 5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.archaius/archaius-core/0.7.5) currently is using `guava version 16.0` then if you want to use `guava version 18.0`
You need to add the dependency by following way:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I think it is an issue of version typo when packing the jar what you are having.

Comment: Even ,`hystrix javanica 1.5.2` is using an older guava version that is 15 0 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-javanica/1.5.12

Comment: I added the dependency but it is still not considering it. Somehow cassandra jars and hysterix jar are not working together

Comment: But from Abdus 's screenshot , he is already using guava 18.0 now......

Comment: @AbdusSamad yeah, perhaps Cassandra and hystrix versions are not compatible, that can be the issue.

Comment: @KenChan yes. As I mentioned it is possible some issue of typo when packing the jar version. I'd need to put in context what he does

Comment: You need to add this as a direct dependency. i.e. not in dependencyManagement. Maven will pick the dependency that is closest to your web application in the dependency tree. You cannot get any closer than by having it in your pom.xml. That said, backward compatibility between major Guava versions has not been great in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

It reminds me the class loading issue when I work with Glassfish4 long time ago. From the [docs](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Developer_Guide.html#class-loading-precedence) , the classes will first load from the following order before loading from the `lib` in the WAR :

> (1) System Dependencies - These are dependencies that are added to the
>   module automatically by the container, including the Java EE api’s.
>
> (2) User Dependencies - These are dependencies that are added through
>   jboss-deployment-structure.xml or through the Dependencies: manifest
>   entry.

It also mentions that the dependencies in (1) can be excluded through by the use of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

And from [this](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Developer_Guide.html#jboss-deployment-structure-file) ,  `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` should be placed inside `/WEB-INF/` and can prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies by :

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>


     <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
    <exclusions>
        <module name="com.google.guava" />
    </exclusions>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Actually I don't know how to find the module name of the Guava module, I just search the docs and Github and found there is a one called `com.google.guava` .

I am also not sure it will work or not. But hope to give you some direction .Good luck.

Comment: This is not necessary as WildFly implementation jars are not normally visible to applications - only the Java EE apis will be visible.

Comment: How did you learn spring? I am trying to learn spring but failed so far. I need your help. Can you provide me with some resource to learn it? I really need help. I want to learn to create a website in spring @KenChan

Comment: Hi Steve, But it is what I read from the WildFly docs, sometime it will first load the JAR shipped by WildFly before loading the lib from the WAR

Comment: @Pie , I remember I read a book called "spring in action" back to the time when I learn spring. Looking at the official documentation also provide some resource. After I get a decent overview knowledge about spring, I like to look at the sources codes..